# Validating custom domain in Azure App service by using only TXT record

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service

When adding a custom domain (our corporate apex domain in this case) to an Azure App Service it says that I need to add a TXT record and change the A record. In this case we're moving our corporate website so I cannot change the A record before everything is setup so I would like to do this in steps:

1. Add the TXT record to our Dns
2. Add the custom domain in the App Service
3. Change the A record in our Dns

I couldn't test this because I didn't want to create a dummy domain and create tickets to our dns provider with this.

So is it possible to do it like the steps above?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to validate a custom domain by adding just the TXT record and switch the A record later:

1. Get domain verification ID from the Azure portal.
2. Add the TXT record using your DNS provider.
3. Create and validate the custom domain for your app service in Azure portal.
4. Make changes to the A record when you are ready to switch the main domain to new website.

I had the same question in the past because Azure portal instructions sound like both TXT and A records are required for domain validation. Microsoft have recently published an article with step-by-step guide for the active DNS scenario, you can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain).