# Change domain name mapping from A record to CNAME in Azure without downtime

Tags: azure

I have a website (example.com used as an example in the following) hosted on Azure with Cloudflare in front. I also have a subdomain, blog.example.com, hosted on Azure with Cloudflare in front. The subdomain is configured using the, now legacy, approach using a DNS `A` record pointing at the Azure IP of the servers hosting this website. I would like to change this to the, now default, way of setting this up using a `CNAME` record pointing to the website name on Azure.

My question is this. Can I change this without any downtime? I cannot create a `CNAME` record with the name `blog` as long as I have an `A` record with the same name. And I cannot create the new `CNAME` based domain mapping on Azure as long as the `CNAME` record is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### DNS configuration

> I cannot create a `CNAME` record with the name `blog` as long as I have an `A` record with the same name.

This is true, DNS providers usually do not allow to have both `A` and `CNAME` records for the same subdomain because this configuration can lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Depending on your DNS provider, you should be able to do one of the following things:

- Modify the existing DNS record and change it from `A` to `CNAME` record type
- Some providers do not support this operation but can recommend a workaround similar to this:

  1. Create `CNAME` record for the `blog` subdomain
  2. Wait for at least 5 minutes (depending on your TTL) for changes to propagate
  3. Delete the old A record

Reach out to your DNS provider to find what is the best approach for switching between different record types.

##### Azure configuration

> And I cannot create the new `CNAME` based domain mapping on Azure as long as the `CNAME` record is not created.

This is not correct - you **can** create a custom domain and validate it in Azure by using just a `TXT` record and repoint the `CNAME` record later. Find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734273/validating-custom-domain-in-azure-app-service-by-using-only-txt-record/71772841#71772841).

So you should perform the switch in the following order to avoid downtime:

1. Start creating a custom domain for `blog.example.com` in Azure Portal to get the required `TXT` record details.
2. Create the TXT record for domain ownership validation.
3. Finish custom domain creation in Azure.
4. Re-configure your `A` record `blog.example.com` as `CNAME` pointing to the new Azure domain.

Comment: This is very useful and interesting. Thank you so much. Just to clear things out. In step 1 of the Azure part, this is only done to get the value of the `TXT` record, right? I mean, I'm not able to save the custom domain at this point.

Comment: @ThomasArdal yes, that's right, step 1 is needed just to get the TXT record value, you will be able to save this custom domain only after adding this TXT record to DNS.